# How do I reset IIS programmatically?

Tags: iis

Is there any alternative to the IIS Administrative UI that can be used to reset IIS from a program?..

now we have created a batch file if iis reset and scheduled it every hour......

i just wanted something so that we should not be able to reset iis....

Comment: What do you mean? what do you need? please more details, the question title is something and the question text is talking about something else.

Comment: assume you need to be able to go to a special page and effect a server restart?

Comment: actually my prob is i dont have much knowledge about the .net but of java..some project is deployed at our client site of .net..

which is getting down in a day lot of time..so i need some code or alternative to make that beeter....and i should not need to reset thee iis...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the WMI interface, you can programatically recycle the AppPool

Use MgmtClassGen from the SDK to generate your WMI class:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\Bin\mgmtclassgen" IIsApplicationPool        /n root\MicrosoftIISv2 /l VB /p IIsApplicationPool.vb
```

-or-

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\Bin\mgmtclassgen" IIsApplicationPool        /n root\MicrosoftIISv2 /l CS /p IIsApplicationPool.cs
```

Then use this in your code:

```
Dim msScope As New ManagementScope("root\MicrosoftIISv2")
Dim wmiIISAppPool As IIsApplicationPool
Try
    wmiIISAppPool = New IIsApplicationPool(msScope, String.Format("W3SVC/AppPools/{0}", _AppPoolID))
    'Recycle it
    wmiIISAppPool.Recycle()

Catch ex As Exception
    LogEvent("    *** ERROR - AppPoolRecycle failed: AppPoolID: {0} {1}", _AppPoolID, ex.Message)
Finally
    If Not wmiIISAppPool Is Nothing Then wmiIISAppPool.Dispose()
End Try
```

Comment: WMI is a rich toolset for all admin tasks and is the most secure remote access into a Win server. I've used WMI for several other tasks including installing apps across servers via SMS.

Comment: Basically, MgmtClassGen gives you a strongly typed object given your WMI class.  So the code creates a WMI IIsApplicationPool object tied to the Application Pool name (String.Format("W3SVC/AppPools/{0}", _AppPoolID).  It exposes a method called Recycle() that uses WMI to recycle the app pool.

Comment: i m not very new  in .net and deployed at clientside....how will i use it ....my subject is java..from where should i call it...

Comment: it will be recyling the application pool......and not exactly resetting the iis i think soo.......plz update

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [IIS Admin API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526050.aspx), in particular the [IIisServiceControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525399.aspx) interface.

Comment: actually my prob is i dont have much knowledge about the .net but of java..some project is deployed at our client site of .net..

which is getting down in a day lot of time..so i need some code or alternative to make that beeter....and i should not need to reset thee iis...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use iisreset from command prompt to restart all of IIS.

I believe tvanfossan answer is ok but the interface he recommends I think can only reset all of IIS once.  You may want to programmatically identify which process running in your application pool you want to kill if you have a hung process.

I suggest looking at the scripting interfaces as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526050.aspx

Answer (score 0):

there is file called iisreset.exe in system32 folder.  You can create a batch to execute it.